# How do I turn a select list into a radio button?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a `list text` field that I want to display as a series of radio buttons instead of a select (dropdown) list.  In Drupal 7, I could change this on **Manage fields**.  How can I do that in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

step 1 : choose the field type is  "list(text)".

step 2 : change the "Allowed number of values" as *limited* in **Field settings**

step 3 : change the "field widget" as *Check boxes/radio buttons* in **Manage form display**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This option moved.  It is now under **Manage form display**, which is next to **Manage fields**.

You will also need the Options module (included in core) enabled.